# Declaring JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

What's the best practice of declaring javascript variables and why?

For example from these 3 below, which one is better?

```
var test1;
var test2 = null;
var test3 = "";
```

Thanks.

Comment: That solely depends on what for and how you're going to use them.

Comment: "better" is a subjective term. The **real** best way would be to **be consistent with the rest of your team and codebase**.

Comment: Define best!Readability?Space?

Comment: I just wanted to know what other developers think as a "better" way to do declare them. That's all. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"best"* way is the way you and your colleagues decide upon and verify with a linting tool.

Here are some suggestions:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
a = false;
b = "";
c = {};
```

-

```
var a = false;
var b = "";
var c = {};
```

-

```
var a = false, b = "", c = {};
```

-

```
var a = false,
    b = "",
    c = {};
```

-

```
var a, b, c;
a = false;
b = "";
c = {};
```

I don't know enough about the different JavaScript engine vendors to make this statement but my assumption is that all of the above are functionally and performance equivalent. If you are using a minifying tool like YUICompiler or Google Closure Compiler the above samples will all compile to the same output*.

<sub>* It looks like Google Closure Compiler likes to keep the `var` and definition separate if you had that in your original code. `var a,b,c;a=!1;b="";c={};` vs `var a=!1,b="",c={};`</sub>

Comment: consistency consistency consistency